# Angular way to toggle require on a password field whether create new or edit user?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm writing a small Angular-based web application to manage access to a pool of documents for download. User permission is managed by a four step routine: (a) administrator fills a "create new user" blank form where password is required (this is not a public website thus the admin defines the user's password); (b) admin lists all users; (c) admin picks one user from the list by clicking an "edit user" button; (d) admin edits user data on a form identical to the create new user one except that password is optional and entered only if its change is intended.

Currently "create new" and "edit existing" forms are separate files to account for differences in headings and the password field required status but I'm trying to merge them into a single form. I have succeeded in all details except for making the password input field required when loading the form as "create new" and not required when loading the same form for "edit user" purposes.

After doing my bit of research on stackoverflow I have tried ngRequired=expression as follows:

```
 <input type="text" name="user_password" data-ng-model="user_password" data-ng-required="user_password.password_required">
```

On the create new controller, `password_required` is defined as

```
(...)
$scope.password_required = true;
(...)
```

whereas in the edit user controller the same line is

```
(...)
$scope.password_required = false;
(...)
```

But that is simply not changing the input field required condition at all. Any suggestions to a improvements or to a different approach within Angular (ie, not adding javascript code to the view) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dsttaw12/1/

Comment: Your expression in the view is `user_password.password_required`, not `password_required`. So change the expression in the view.

Comment: Hi, many thanks but I'm a bit confused. Is using the element name's before the $scope variable name wrong?

Comment: Yes, its wrong. Variables in angular expressions are evaluated on the scope. So if you use foo.bar in an expression, it will evaluate it as $scope.foo.bar. As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks all for comments and clarifications! It's working fine now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to stick with `ng-model` and `ng-required` which has allowed for dynamically required fields in the past, but I also don't need my code to run through an HTML5 validator.  As I understand it that's one of the few things different when using the `data-` prefix.

If you don't need validation, then with your example:

```
<input type="text"
       name="user_password"
       ng-model="user_password"
       ng-required="password_required">
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I don't need any validation except for required. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: JB Nizet caught the error (in your original post comments).  You're actually attributing the `data-ng-required` to `$scope.user_password.password_required` rather than `$scope.password_required`.  Correcting your `data-ng-required` to be simply `password_required` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

U are missing the variable name.
Please see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pg0s96tp/3/)

```
<input type="text" name="user_password" data-ng-model="user_password" data-ng-required="password_required">
```

And in controller

```
$scope.password_required = true;
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks but I'm a bit confused. Is using the element name's before the $scope variable name wrong?

Comment: U can use . But in controller u shud use $scope.user_password={"password_required" : true};   see http://jsfiddle.net/pg0s96tp/4/